# No Make or GCC on my OSX

Tags: macos

I'm new with OSX. When I open a terminal I don't have `make` or `gcc`; however I have installed `xcode` so from what I have read they should by somewhere on the OS.

What should I do?

Comment: If you've got xcode you should have gcc and make. my gcc is in /usr/bin/ same with make, with xcode 4.2

Comment: @daven11 that's because you haven't experienced the pleasure (or pain) that is Xcode 4.3 yet.

Comment: ahh, pays to be a late adopter :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Apple Developer website](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/), log in and then look for "Command Line Development Tools".  They should be found at [https://developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Logging in is important as you need to do this to get access to these specific tools.

Comment: If you have XCode (and can compile a simple C program), then you already have gcc. Where, I don't know, but I've heard Apple's flavor of gcc has some compatibility issues...

Comment: @jpaugh - You may "already have" gcc somewhere, but the command line tools make building from the Terminal command line a lot more easy, if not simply downright possible.  My guess is that gcc is probably buried somewhere deep down inside the Xcode app package (which is where Apple is hiding most things these days instead of "`/Developer`") and the "gcc" installed by the tools installer essentially points (or links or whatever) to the current compiler is (llvm, etc.).

Comment: I wasn't aware Mac offered gcc separately. Sorry. At any rate, it seems a waste to have two just because Xcode is selfish.